# Python check if something in a Text file Was in an Excel File

Tags: python, regex, excel, openpyxl

I have to check if every value in a structured text file (the table layout was made by spaces) was inside an Excel file. So I have started like this to make sure that I have all I need:

```
data = []
lt = 'unknown'

with open('VW.txt') as f_input:
    for row in f_input:
        data_row = re.match(r'(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(.{8}) +(.*)|LT +: (\w+)', row)

        if data_row:
            if data_row.groups()[0]:
                data.append([lt] + list(data_row.groups()[:-1]))
            else:
                lt = data_row.groups()[-1]
```

In `data` I have the list of lines in the text file. Now I have to check for every line if `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` is also in some line of the Excel file then skip, if not create another list with only the missing lines.

I have tried so many times and in many ways, but the only result that I can get is a list of four elements (and these are not the same as if I check with a sheet)

I am using OpenPyxl to go through the Excel.

`VW.txt` example:

```
LISON                 Kontoauszug                          10.07.2016     20:13
                  Monat/Jahr: 06.16                                  Seite:   1

Lief. : 000526070 Company Name (V Sachbearb.: Name Surname
LT    : VW0012    Lief.-Eigene.:    0                  Tel.: Phone

Saldo Vorm.:     170  BEL.:     253 ENTL:     181 Endsaldo:      242

B-Dat  Abs/Empfae   BEL.    ENTL   Saldo  BA  Bel-Nr    WK-LG-LR   Bemerkung
050416 000590178       0       1     169  50  16103483  49-12-00   FEHLER IM SY
050416 000590178       0       1     168  50  16103484  49-16-00   FEHLER IM SY
050516 000590030       0       2     166  50  16104633  16-01-K1
160516 000590030       0       1     165  50  16104980  16-01-K1
170516 000590030       0       2     163  50  16105015  16-01-K1
210516 000590120       1       0     164  51     36873  37-  -     000590120
230516 000590178       1       0     165  51  16105229  49-16-00   NSURNAME
240516 000590030       0       2     163  50  16105243  16-01-K1
300516 000590030       0       1     162  50  16105484  16-01-K1
300516 000590030       0       1     161  50  16105483  16-01-K1
310516 000590030       2       0     163  51    697321  26-  -     NSURNAME
310516 000590030       0       2     161  50  16105536  16-01-K1
310516 000590030       0       1     160  50  16105542  16-01-K1
010616 000590120       2       0     162  21     39694  37-  -     000590120
010616 000710030      12       0     174  21    627948  21-  -     000710030
010616 000590120       0       1     173  50     39694  37-  -
030616 000712550       0       2     171  10  16105627  28-05-60
030616 000710130       0       1     170  10  16105628  11-01-K4
030616 000448489       0       2     168  10  16105638  18-66-23
030616 000590120       0       2     166  10  16105626  37-75-I4
060616 000590030      41       0     207  21    698299  26-  -     000590030
070616 000712550       0       2     205  10  16105714  28-05-60
070616 000712550       0       1     204  10  16105717  28-08-60
070616 000590178       0       1     203  10  16105710  49-16-
070616 000590120       0       1     202  10  16105702  37-75-I4
070616 000590120       0       1     201  10  16105703  37-78-I4
070616 000590120       0       1     200  10  16105704  37-78-I8
070616 000590235       0       1     199  10  16105707  33-07-K9
070616 000710030       0       1     198  10  16105715  24-06-S2
070616 000590030       0       1     197  10  16105716  16-01-K1
070616 000590030       0       1     196  10  16105722  16-01-K1
070616 000590030       0       3     193  10  16105726  16-01-K1
070616 000711420       0       1     192  10  16105706  40-01-K1
080616 000590120       1       0     193  21     31456  37-  -     000590120
080616 000590120       1       0     194  21     31456  37-  -     000590120
080616 000710030       2       0     196  21    630076  21-  -     000710030
080616 000710030       2       0     198  21    630076  21-  -     000710030
080616 000710030       4       0     202  21    630076  21-  -     000710030
080616 000710136       0       1     201  10  16105769  15-01-F4
090616 000590178       2       0     203  21    491379  49-  -     000590178
090616 000710030       0       1     202  10  16105842  21-01-P0
090616 000710030       0       4     198  10  16105843  21-01-P0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- COMPANY SITE                                          Behaltermanagement -
BA=10 Entlast. durch Lieferschein       BA=11 Belast. durch Lieferschein
BA=20 Entlast. durch PV-Schein          BA=21 Belast. durch PV-Schein
BA=22 Entlast. durch MRV-/Lieferschein  BA=23 Belast. durch MRV-/Lieferschein
BA=30 Entlast. durch Querverkehr        BA=31 Belast. durch Querverkehr
BA=50 Entlast. durch Korrektur          BA=51 Belast. durch Korrektur
BA=70 Entlast. durch Inventurangleich   BA=71 Belast. durch Inventurangleich
BA=NE Entlast. durch NeG neutr. Buch.   BA=NB Belast. durch NeG neutr. Buch.
BA=NK Neukauf                           BA=VS Verschrottung
BA=NW Neukauf Wertersatz                BA=NR Neukauf Recycling
BA=VR Verschrottung Recycling





LISON                 Kontoauszug                          10.07.2016     20:13
                  Monat/Jahr: 06.16                                   Seite:   2

Lief. : 000526070 COMPANY NAME (V Sachbearb.: NAME SURNAME
LT    : VW0012    Lief.-Eigene.:    0                  Tel.: PHONE

Saldo Vorm.:     170  BEL.:     253 ENTL:     181 Endsaldo:      242

B-Dat  Abs/Empfae   BEL.    ENTL   Saldo  BA  Bel-Nr    WK-LG-LR   Beme
```

The Excel file:

```
|Material|MaterialDesc|MovimentType|MaterialDoc|Quantity|Date|DDT|CompanyRif|
```

For like 700 rows.

It is like:

Ok I have the LT number that is equal to our boxcode.
So I have to check

```
VW0012 | B-Dat | Entl or Bel | Bel-Nr
```

If they are in one row of my Excel, then they are sync with us and we do not need to do anything, but if for some reason, the values do not appear in the Excel file, then we have to tell the other company to modify what they have written.

Comment: Use the the csv module in Python to read the file.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add a sample of rows from both your `VW.txt` file and also your Excel file.

Comment: Maybe like this is better?

Comment: So, you're checking if every value in the columns is somewhere in an Excel sheet? That sounds extremely inefficient. But you probably want to use some kind of nested loop. I think you should probably focus on telling us which values from the CSV you want to check against which values in the Excel file.

Comment: I hope it's better explained

Comment: I think this is probably too much for a single SO question. You probably want to break this task down into components, the main one is getting the relevant data from your source into another data structure.

Comment: I've already have a list of lists that's been generated by the .txt... I've only to check this with the Excel file... But maybe it's something so strong to do...